# WPF, xaml Cad or drawing app examples?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, sample, cad

I am trying to learn WPF and xaml and am writing a cad style geometry app for my kids.  Does anyone know of an existing example written in VB.net?  C# is fine as well.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Any thoughts/examples on how to structure such an app?  TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first step would be to create a custom canvas that contains the ability to hold and draw shapes. This is the critical part of the application. Things like a grid, snapping to edges will need to be implemented.

Then i would look into the range of Shapes that your kids might draw, squares, rectangles, circles, things like that.

Deciding on a document format is important as it will partially help you design some of your code. Using an XML format will be good for serialization and other things.

Then start building the front end, toolbars, etc.

It's a bit tricky to know where to start, but I would start with the custom canvas. This is the most important part and if you can get this functioning efficiently and effectively, the rest will be easier.

Just some thoughts for you to work on :)

Answer (score 4):

It might be simpler than you think. If you have previous experience with stuff like linear algebra and 3-D to 2-D projections, even simpler.

Take a look at this intro tutorial go get a taste for what and how simple WPF can be to treat 3-D stuff:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/IntroductionTo3D.html
[image]

Comment: Thanks Padu but the link seems to be recursive.

Comment: Sorry about that. Hope this one helps.

Answer (score 1):

monoworks maybe the one you are looking for...

Find it here: http://monoworksproject.org/